# How to manipulate outlook custom form, fill combo boxes and staff

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

we have a working outlook form in our company which includes a button in outlook ribbon

By clicking it a **New Mail** window opens which has the designed custom form with some combo-boxes, the printscreen image is attached [image: the form looks like this]

Below this form there are some **VB Macro**s which fills the combo-boxes and runs some code and when we click **Send**, a new mail which has this form will be sent for the recipient(s) **The Problem is**: the recipient receives the vb macros behind this form and sometimes this macros will be accidentally modified and ..., so we don't like this approach

Currently I'm working on a **C# VSTO** project to replace a AddIn(.dll) with this macro.

My first solution: I have imported a copy of the custom form as a form region and add combo-boxes and other controls in it and fill them and everything was ok[image: My Form looks like this], but this form have not been sent by mail to recipient!

My Second solution: I think it would be better to remove all macros from the old custom form and try to fill combo-boxes of the old custom form in my AddIn.

My Question is which solution is better? Is there a better way to do this?

I think I'm going wrong direction because of lack of knowledge with VSTO and outlook forms. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook custom forms is an old approach. Defintely, form regions is the better way to go. But it requires better coding skills. Be aware, Outlook form regions can't be sent to recipients with the item.

You need to have the Outlook add-in installed on both sides (sender and recipients) if you want to see the data entered on the form region. Moreover, you have to create corresponding user properties on the item being sent. On the recipient side your add-in can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/application-newmailex-event-outlook) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. So, you may read user properties and display on the form region. Also you may consider using any web server (web service) for uploading such data there. In that case you will be sure the data is preserved when user properties are truncated on the recipient side.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, you mean I should create a plain message, add my fields as properties and send it to recipient, then on recipient display those fields in my form region(One form for send and one for receive)?

Comment: A single form can be used for that. Be aware, the properties can be erased on the recipient side if correspoding user properties are not defined for the store.